# JPA + Hibernate. Different column type for production and testing environment

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have gone through all the existing questions on stackoverflow, although those questions looks similar, but none answer solved the problem, and the question is not the repeated one.

In production we are planning to use PostgreSQL, and for testing environment H2.
We have models

```
 @TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)})
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "consumer_details")
  public class ConsumerDetails implements Serializable {
  private String name;
  @Type(type = "json")
  private ConsumerRequest info;
 }

 public class ConsumerRequest implements Serializable {
   private String clientName;
 }
```

Postgres supports data type Json and Jsonb. We are saving ConsumerRequest as column named "info" with data type as Jsonb in ConsumerDetails table. To support Json, we overiden Postgres dialect as

```
  public class CustomPostgresqlDialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {
    public CustomPostgresqlDialect() {
      super();
      this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb");
    }
}
```

This works fine for prod environment backed by Postgres. But does not work for testing environment in H2 DB as H2 DB does not support json data type. I tried overriding H2Dialect as

```
public class CustomH2Dialect extends H2Dialect {
   public CustomH2Dialect() {
      super();
      this.registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "json");
   }
}
```

But it does not work and I gets exception as

```
WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 90026, SQLState: 90026
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - 
Serialization failed, cause: "java.io.NotSerializableException: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode" [90026-196]
```

Any idea how to solve this for testing environment.

Comment: It's quite simple: use Postgres for your testing environment. It's free, and easy to install. And most importantly: it makes little sense to spend time testing something that will never be in production, and it's important to test what will go in production. By testing with H2, and not testing with Postgres, you effectively find bugs that happen with H2, and don't find any bug that happen with Postgres.

Comment: @OP: Wondering if you find a way to come around it to work with H2 itself or not.